# How to Do "Add perfix... to qml.qrc in QT Creator"?

Tags: qt, qml, prefix

I'm new to Qt creator, so when I want to add a prefix folder to my qml.qrc file just nothing happens!
I right-click on the "qml. qrc" file and press "Add Prefix...", then choose my folder name like "folder", then press "OK", But nothing happens!
please help me, I think my app has a problem with its installation, hope I'm mistaking!

my OS = windows10
my QT = Qt creator 4.15 based on 5.15.2

Answer (score 0):

1. Select `qrc`  and select open in Editor

[image]

2. Select add Prefix

[image]

[image]

3. **Then you should add File to see prefix name in project I add icon**

[image]

[image]

4.Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> , and Save Project you will see it :

[image]